# return index of the first letter of a specific substring of a string

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I am given a string and I wish to find out the index of the first character of a substring of that string whenever it appears the very first time in the parent string.

For example, given a string "itiswhatitis" and the substring "is", the output should be 2.

Comment: Did you look at the `String` class API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding index of a substring in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000039/finding-index-of-a-substring-in-java)

Comment: What have you tried? Post it, so that people can tell you if you're right or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use as below

```
int indexOf(String str)
```

from your example string.

```
String s ="itiswhatitis";

int index = s.indexOf("is");
```

Comment: And the API:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#IndexOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

```
"itiswhatitis".indexOf("is")
```

Try this

Comment: And the API :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#IndexOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index = "itiswhatitis".indexOf("is");
    System.out.println(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str="itiswhatitis";
int index=str.indexOf("is");
```