# How to search for a substring from an user input string and print out

Tags: java, string

So I have an assignment where the user puts in a string and a word, and then the program will search for this word in the string and print it out with starting index.

For example if the user inputs this string:

> abccbaabcccabbcacbbbca

And this word:

> ab

The program will print out this:

> 1 abccbaabcccabbcacbbbca
>
> 7 abcccabbcacbbbca
>
> 12 abbcacbbbca
>
> 3 casualities were found

As I just started taking classes in Java, I have only learned about basic loops (for, while), and just learning to use a few methods from the string-class including:

int compareTo()

boolean equals()

Int ength()

static String valueOf()

char charAt()

int indexOf

String substring

String toLowerCase/UpperCase()

String trim()

As far as I am concerned, I am supposed to use these methods in a for-loop, but I am not sure how to do this. The scanning of the user input string needs to be casesensetive as well. Could anyone come up with an example or explanation on how to do this? An example with explanation would be appreciated.

Edit 1: @ Zong Zheng Li, I don't see how my question is a duplicate of your linked question when it only adresses  to one aspect of my question.

Comment: Try taking a closer look at the documentation for `indexOf`.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [return index of the first letter of a specific substring of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025654/return-index-of-the-first-letter-of-a-specific-substring-of-a-string)

Comment: I understand you don't have enough rep but please try not to use edits to reply. Think about your problem in parts. Do you know how to read user input? Can you use `indexOf` with the inputs? Can you do this repeatedly and count number of iterations? Do you know how to print output? The solutions to these subproblems can be easily found on this website. Just take it one step at a time.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't realize I shouldn't edit to answer. It just popped up that I should edit to explain why my question was different. Anyway, I have only written the part of my code where I let the user write in string and word. I'm not sure how to build my code after this. It's a bit confusing what to search for since I am not learning Java in English. Could you link me questions that adresses these problems for me?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop, where (without giving away the code):

- the iteration variable is initially set to the index of the word in the text
- the terminating condition is where the index returned is -1
- the next value is the index of the substring *after* the current index value

In the body of the loop, print out the substring of the text from the index onwards.

To count the number of times a match was found, declare another variable before the loop and set it to zero. Inside the loop, increment it by one.
After the loop print out the value of the counter.

The methods you'll need are [`indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-), [`indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) and [`substring(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-).

Comment: Could you give an example? I am not learning Java in English, so it is a bit confusing for me what you just wrote there. Help appreciated although

Edit: Thanks for listing up needed methods